# How to get first char of string in python?

Tags: python, string, char, cpu-word

I want to  enter a word from keyboard, put it in a string variable and return first and last letter from the word. But I don't know to to do this.

```
input: "Hello"
output: "H", "o"
```

P.S: I want to put this 2 letters in a variable:

```
print(first)
output:"H"
print(last)
output:"o"
```

Please give me a solution!

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: I don't have any idea

Comment: for first letter `input[0]` and last letter `input[-1]`

Comment: Have you tried Google ?

Answer (score 12):

simply.

```
st = "hello"
print st[0] #first char
print st[-1] #last char
```